# How do I print a list from a class in python?

Tags: python, oop

Ive done C++ classes now im learning Python so the classes are new to me. Im trying to simply do some experimenting. I have created two for loops to create every possible combination of fpok from size 1 to 9. However, how do I print the outputs? In other words how do I print the list possibleStringList from this class?

```
import itertools

class TestClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.possibleStringList = []
        self.possibleStringList.append("")
        
        for i in range(1, 9):
            for str in itertools.product("fpok", repeat=i):
                self.possibleStringList.append(str)
```

Thank you.

Comment: The same way you print *anything*?

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry maybe I should have made that more clear. How can I print this list OUTSIDE of this class?

Comment: @Crunchy, [voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (up or down) is part of our culture in SO. Don't feel offended because you got a down vote. It is never personal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `print` function.

```
test_class = TestClass()
print(test_class.possibleStringList)
```

Comment: @alexpdv thank you. Yes! the **test_class = TestClass()** is the syntax I was missing. I understand the use of the print function. Thank you very much